# How to get the age of a person when having their dates of birth in a column of the type 'object'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python with several columns, one of which is date of birth of persons. The data type of the date of birth column is object. I would like to get the age of persons as an integer number.

For example: date of birth = 23.6.2005 gives (as today is 1.5.2021) age = 15 (years)

The ages are to be returned in a column of the dataframe.

Comment: Subtract `datetime.date.today()` from each element in the column to get a timedelta, and then take the `days // 365` of that timedelta

Answer (score 0):

It may work for you

```
import datetime 

today = datetime.date.today()
df["age"] = ((today - df["DOB"]).dt.days //365.25)
```

Comment: After executing this

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
today = dt.date.today()
df["age"] = ((today - df["date_of_birth"]).dt.days /365.25).apply(math.floor)

I get: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

There needs to be a datatype conversion of the dataframe column date_of_birth.

Comment: df['date_of_birth']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'])

Comment: your date_of_birth column is not of date type convert it into datetime using above line of code

Comment: After the conversion: df['date_of_birth']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'])

and executing

df['age'] = (datetime.date.today() - df['date_of_birth']) // dt.timedelta(days=365.25)

I get this error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'

The problem is that date_of_birth must be date, but it is datetime. I tried this conversion, but it did not work:

df['date_of_birth'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date_of_birth'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()

error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: I got it. I used today = datetime.datetime.today() so the formats match.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It was a seemingly simple issue, but it got very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.date.today()` to get the current date, and subtract the column from that, and then divide by a timedelta of one year for a reasonably accurate measurement.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

p = pd.DataFrame({'birthdate': [datetime.date(1969,5,21), datetime.date(1996, 8, 15), datetime.date(1981, 4, 30)]})
#     birthdate
# 0  1969-05-21
# 1  1996-08-15
# 2  1981-04-30

p['age'] = (datetime.date.today() - p['birthdate']) // datetime.timedelta(days=365.25)
#     birthdate  age
# 0  1969-05-21   51
# 1  1996-08-15   24
# 2  1981-04-30   40
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your contribution. I just needed datetime.datetime.today() so the formats matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date difference by substracting [`pd.Timestamp.now()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.now.html) to your date of birth column (with conversion from 'object' format to datetime format).  Then divide by [`np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) (which mean 1 year time difference.  Use numpy function since Pandas has no corresponding function with up to year time difference.)

```
df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.to_datetime(df['date of birth'])) // np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

Rounding down to integer age is automatically achieved through division by `//`

### Demo

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date of birth': ['23.6.2005', '22.4.1995', '12.12.2002']})

df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.to_datetime(df['date of birth'])) // np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')

print(df)

  date of birth  age
0     23.6.2005   15
1     22.4.1995   26
2    12.12.2002   18
```